# Law of iterated logarithm and hitting time distribution

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_i$ be a collection of independent standard normal variables and $S_n = \sum_1^n X_i$. The by the law of iterated logarithm

$${S_n \over \sqrt{2n \log \log n}} > 0.8$$

infinitely often, where $0.8$ is arbitrary and could be any number less than $1$.

Is anything known about the probability distribution of the smallest $n$ for which the above condition holds?

My question is motivated by numerical experiments where even for large $N$, a large fraction of paths don't meet the above condition for any $n<N$.

Comment: [This](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.2639.pdf) paper addresses this in the case that $X_i$ are Rademacher random variables rather than standard normals.  Their methods could probably be extended to your case.

Answer (score 0):

If the boundary is at a higher value (instead of 0.8) then you can approximate the random walk as a Wiener process or diffusion and the distribution for the waiting time will be approximately a Levy distribution.

The derivation of that distribution can be done by considering the [reflection principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle_(Wiener_process)). A complicating issue with your situation is that you do not have an absorbing state in a single point. So the use of a Levy distribution only works when the boundary is at a high value such that considering the absorbing state as a single point is approximately true.

In your situation, where a large fraction does not reach the boundary, you can consider the approximation to work well.